Lebesgue Stieltjes measure theorem
I’ve been desperately trying to find a proof for the following theorem
$$
\int f\,\mathrm{d}\mu_G = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)G'(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
on the screenshot for $f$ being a measurable function
$f: \mathbb{R}\to [0,\infty]$
and the Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure $\mu_G$ with $\mu_G((s,t])= G(t)-G(s)$ for all $s\leq t$ and $G$ being continuously differentiable.
I would really appreciate if someone knew a proof for this since I need that for an exam.
theorem to be proved
Many thanks!

Welcome to community, even though I correct the latex of your original text, I wonder if some expression in your problem needs more justify.

Thanks! I don’t really know which expressions you mean that might be unclear

Try characteristic functions to start with. Is $G$ increasing?
